# Get javascript variable's value in Django python url template tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have a django template section

```
{% for l in items%}

         <td style="text-align: center" 
          id="{{m.id}}_{{m.set|slice:':7' }}_{{m.kidu}}_{{l}}">
         </td>
{% endfor %}
```

and JS section below:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    {% for a in all_results %}
            $('#{{a.id}}_{{a.set|slice:":7"}}_{{ a.kidu}}_{{ a.adi|slice:":2" }}').html('{{  a.id }}');
            $('#{{a.id}}_{{a.set|slice:":7"}}_{{ a.kidu}}_{{ a.adi|slice:":2" }}').addClass('{{ a.state__name.split|join:"_" }}');
    {% endfor %}
});
</script>
```

What am trying is to pass the id as an href link in my template, so that once the user click on the link he will redirected to that particular record detail view.

I tried as follows:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    {% for a in all_results %}
            $('#{{a.id}}_{{a.set|slice:":7"}}_{{ a.kidu}}_{{ a.adi|slice:":2" }}').html('{{ href="{% url 'req_detail_view' a.id %}"}}');
            $('#{{a.id}}_{{a.set|slice:":7"}}_{{ a.kidu}}_{{ a.adi|slice:":2" }}').addClass('{{ a.state__name.split|join:"_" }}');
    {% endfor %}
});
</script>
```

But am getting as `Could not parse the remainder: '="{% url 'req_detail_view' a.id %}"' from 'href="{% url 'req_detail_view' a.id %}"'` Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `.html('{{ href="{% url 'req_detail_view' a.id %}"}}');` supposed to be doing?

Comment: passing url link with my id to my template(td cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUst remove `{{`, `}}`. Your code should be,

```
.html("href=\"{% url 'req_detail_view' a.id %}\"");
```

or

```
.html("<a href=\"{% url 'req_detail_view' a.id %}\">Click here</a>");
```

`.html` is a jquery/javascript function used to set html to a particular tag. For ex,

`$(#foo a).html("<a href=\"{% url 'req_detail_view' a.id %}\">Click here</a>");`

This would change the html of all the anchor tags present inside the tag having `foo` as id.